# Authorized route

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have some trouble with Spring Security. I declared a given route in the chain filter to be like authorized

```
.antMatchers("/autorized/route/**").permitAll()
```

and I have another route that are not autorized, and requires an access token but when I try to access to the authorized route I get this error:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:379)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:223)\
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) 
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
```

I got the same issue even with:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/autorized/route/**")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
}
```

By the way the method rout is: **POST**

Is there any explication?

Comment: Do you also use expression-based access control (`hasRole`, `hasPermission`, etc.)? It sounds like the exception is coming from that.

Comment: Are you using @Async somewhere. Or you feel its somehow a different thread then the thread which actually received the request.

Comment: when you bypass the chain filter basicly you don't need to mention the roles/permission because you allow it and you work outside of the securityContext that will have no authorized object

Comment: Show your full security configuration. As @DarioSeidl already wrote it looks like you are restricting a URL that is not authenticated.